# How to forbid making copy of array for thread

Tags: php, arrays, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I'm using a pthreads in php. I have two threads for work with array that contains connections of users. When second thread starts it make a copy of this array for himself.  After modifying this array by main thread, second thread don't have new elements. How to forbid making a copy of this array for threads ?

```
class AsyncClass extends Thread
{
    private $_message = null;
    private $_timeout = 0;
    private $connected_users;

    public function __construct($message, $timeout, $connected_users)
    {
        $this->_message = $message;
        $this->_timeout = $timeout;
        $this->connected_users = $connected_users;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        while(true){
            var_export($this->connected_users); // NULL, because is no connected users
            sleep($this->_timeout);
        }

    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English -- it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try to use synchronization methods for this? I don't know you task, but you can try for example [lock](http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.lock.php) or even use [workers](http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php) and [pools](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pool.php) for this issue. Also you can create special class for storing data, inherited from [Stackable](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.stackable.php) which will take care about data safety.